# Accumulation points in $T_1$ space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a $T_1$ space. If $S \subset X$, $S \neq \varnothing$ and $x \in S'$, then every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$.

Once I saw a pretty easy proof by contradiction, but I can't recall the details of it and I don't find it anywhere. The closest I got is this on [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_Points_in_T1_Space), but unless I'm missing something obvious, that's straightly wrong - the intersection of the neighbourhood with the set should be finite in their argument, not necessarily the neighbourhood itself.

Suppose by contradiction that there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(U \setminus \{x\})\cap S$ is finite. This implies $U \cap S$ finite. Since $X$ is $T_1$, we get $U \cap S$ is closed. I'm stuck. Can someone give a hand completing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one approach is something like that. Suppose that there is U open , $x \in U$ which $ (U \setminus \{x\})\cap S $ is finite $ F = \{a_1,a_2,....a_m\}$.
Then, since $(X,τ)$ is $T_1$, for every $a_i$ there are open sets $ U_i $ ,$x\in U_i $ and $a_i \notin U_i $. Consider the $\cap U_i\cap U $ for i=1,2,...,m. Of course this intersection is not empty ($ x\in \cap U_i $). Then, $(\cap U_i \cap U-\{x\}) \cap S $ is empty. That is not possible since $x \in S'$ and $\cap U_i \cap U $ is an open  neighbourhood of x.

Comment: This seems to work. I'm not just seeing why $(\bigcap U_i \setminus \{x\}) \cap S$ is empty. Can you elaborate just a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Of course. The only points inside U and S (together)  are those finite we assumed(The F set) .So when we create a set ($\cap U_i$) which has none of these points of S but only x, means that the above intersection is empty.

Comment: But $(\bigcap U_i \setminus \{x\})$ could have points in $S$ other than the $a_i$. I'm missing something..

Comment: Well, you might mean, why $U_i \cap S$ hasn't some other points different from the F set. This is a good observation. It would be better to consider the set $G= \cap U_i \cap U$. Now, you know that $G \subset U$ so $G \cap S $ is only x

Comment: That works! Thanks again.